# Trigger change on value of form field change

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a liveview form and a text input:

```
<%= search_input :filter, :search, id: "filter_search_field", class: "input", placeholder: "Search", value: @search_field, "phx-debounce": "300"%>
```

Now there is a moment when I want to clear this field programatically, I do this by changing the assign:

```
{:noreply, assign(socket, :search_field, "")}
```

The problem with this is that the `phx-change` event assigned to the form is not triggered.

I also tried to create a JS hook and change the value of the field from the hook, however that does not create event either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, changing value is not enough to trigger change, a `change` event should be emitted, on user input that event is triggered. More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

There are few approaches to handling this now:

1. Creating a hook for input and emit change event on input change. The downside of this is that you will get duplicate events on user input.
2. Adding the hook to the button (in my case I have a reset button). From here you can trigger the event manually.

What I ended up doing is a little different. `Hooks` have a method called `pushEvent`, so I used that to trigger the `handle_event`:

```
Hooks.TestHook = {
  updated(){
    this.pushEvent("filter", {_target: ["filter", "search"], filter: {search: ""}});
  }
}
```

The variant with creating a custom `change` event can be found [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_view/issues/754#issuecomment-608993210).